# Keyboard orientation in UITextView in UIScrollView

Tags: iphone, ios, uiscrollview, uitextfield, uitextview

In my application I am using a `UIScrollView` having `UITextField` and `UITextView`, I did the coding for the keyboard orientation in UITextField. It's working properly, but it's not working for `UITextView`. While editing in `UITextView`, the keyboard is fully hiding the `UITextView`. Here is my code

```
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
  [textField setClearButtonMode:UITextFieldViewModeWhileEditing];
  CGRect textFieldRect = [self.view.window convertRect:textField.bounds fromView:textField];
  CGRect viewRect = [self.view.window convertRect:self.view.bounds fromView:self.view];
  CGFloat midline = textFieldRect.origin.y + 0.5 * textFieldRect.size.height;
  CGFloat numerator = midline - viewRect.origin.y - MINIMUM_SCROLL_FRACTION * viewRect.size.height;
  CGFloat denominator = (MAXIMUM_SCROLL_FRACTION - MINIMUM_SCROLL_FRACTION) * viewRect.size.height;
  CGFloat heightFraction = numerator / denominator;
  if (heightFraction < 0.0) {
    heightFraction = 0.0;
  } else if (heightFraction > 1.0) {
    heightFraction = 1.0;
  }
  UIInterfaceOrientation orientation =
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation];
  if (orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait ||
    orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown) {
    animatedDistance = floor(PORTRAIT_KEYBOARD_HEIGHT * heightFraction);
  } else {
    animatedDistance = floor(LANDSCAPE_KEYBOARD_HEIGHT * heightFraction);
  }
  CGRect viewFrame = self.view.frame;
  viewFrame.origin.y -= animatedDistance;
  [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
  [UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES];
  [UIView setAnimationDuration:KEYBOARD_ANIMATION_DURATION];
  [self.view setFrame:viewFrame];
  [UIView commitAnimations];
}
- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
  CGRect viewFrame = self.view.frame;
  viewFrame.origin.y += animatedDistance;
  [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
  [UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES];
  [UIView setAnimationDuration:KEYBOARD_ANIMATION_DURATION];
  [self.view setFrame:viewFrame];
  [UIView commitAnimations];    
}
```

Can any one help me to clear this?

Answer (score 1):

use delegate method of textview for UITextview
like bellow

```
-(void)textViewDidBeginEditing:(UITextView *)textView;
```

and also

```
-(void)textViewDidEndEditing:(UITextView *)textView;
```

same like textField delegate method

For Example ...

```
-(void)textViewDidBeginEditing:(UITextView *)textView{

    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.3];
    self.view.frame=CGRectMake(0, -100, 320, 460);//just for an example
    [UIView commitAnimations];

}

-(void)textViewDidEndEditing:(UITextView *)textView{
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.3];
    self.view.frame=CGRectMake(0,0, 320, 460);
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

hope this help you..

:)

Comment: also define UITextFieldDelegate in .h file

Comment: in these delegate methods `-(void)textViewDidBeginEditing:(UITextView *)textView;  ` and `-(void)textViewDidEndEditing:(UITextView *)textView;
`
  what should i do

Comment: which code you use in textfield all code use in these method but just  use keyword "textview" instead of "textfield"

Answer (score 0):

You can try the highly recommended "TPKeyboardAvoidingScrollView", available from: [TPKeyboardAvoiding](https://github.com/michaeltyson/TPKeyboardAvoiding)

Answer (score 0):

First add  in your '.h' file

in did load

```
textView.delegate=self;
```

then
given code for textView

```
textView.userinteractionEnabled=YES;
```